# Необходимо отредактировать PHP файл

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть WordPress тема Building landing Page. На ней есть несколько мест недоступных для редактирования инструментами WP. Через DevTools я нашел прописанные ссылки и кнопки, которые нужно отредактировать.

Вопрос: Как найти эти же ссылки и кнопки в файлах PHP на сервере для редактирования?

одна из таких ссылок:

```
<a href="https://rarathemesdemo.com/builders-landing-page/2016/12/28/industrial" class="btn">GET FREE ESTIMATE</a>
```

---

Большое спасибо за советы! Total Commander у меня, конечно же установлен, указанную строку в итоге удалось найти в файле "parent-function.php"

Кроме того, спасибо labdev95, удалив файл promotional.php, я избавился еще от одного блока, перенаправлявшего всех на сайт с шаблоном темы...

На данный момент, может быть кривовато, но вопрос решён.

Comment: А что нужно отредактировать? Если внешний вид - то можно же этот класс в css поправить...

Answer (score 1):

1. Установить на локальном компьютере программу TOTALCMD
2. Скачать обсуждаемый шаблон на упомянутый в п.1 компьютер
3. Начать поиск по файлам, объект поиска - кусок кода типа такого `class="btn">`
4. Если результатов слишком много, искать по родителям этой кнопки

**p.s. не нашел такой шаблон в гугле, поэтому обязателен ответ на вопрос - применяется ли в обсуждаемом шаблоне плагин типа elementor или wpbakery?**
Если да,то придется искать вашу кнопку в базе данных, это печальная судьба всех этих визуальных конструкторов. В этом случае проще будет, как выше ответили, кастомизировать кнопку через дополнительные стили css.

Comment: На дворе 2021 год, какой Total Commander?

Comment: @KAGG Design критикуя-предлагай! ))) Небось что-то облачное плюс вебпак предложишь?))) ой маладежь.. Программа отменная! гугл в помощь! March 25, 2020: Total Commander 9.51 is released.
Various fixes of issues found after the release of 9.50.

Comment: Современные IDE, например, PhpStorm  или VS Code. Файлы проекта индексируются, поиск - мгновенный,  по мере набора строки поиска. Плюс миллион прочих фич для разработки.

Comment: @KAGG Design  еще раз прочитал вопрос - "КАК НАЙТИ..." У него ПРОЕКТА нет как такового, есть покупная тема и надо найти кусочек кода. выочем???Ок, пусть ставит комбайн. Впрочем, мое предсказание сбылось и то хорошо.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, тотал - правильный **файл**менеджер на все времена (и меня лично удивляют разработчики,  пользующиеся проводником). А IDE большинсву нафик не надо - никаких "проектов" у них нет. Достаточно правильного блокнота, чтобы внести корректировки в шаблоны темы.

Comment: помимо  Total Commander есть еще толковые WinSCP, FileZilla, Cyberduck, Far Manager. Кроме того, уж в 21-м то году все заходят на сервер по ssh и может работать по локальной копии сайта *(не боевой конечно)* через `(mosh) + tmux + vim + (vifm | mc | nnn) + (fzf | ack | ripgrep)`. Кстати, `ack` или `ripgrep` (на выбор) справятся с поиском ссылок в файле на ура.

Comment: @DiD 1. это не файлменеджеры, а FTP клиенты. 2. Никогда не надо говорить за всех. Большинство понятия не имеет об ssh, а командной строки бояться как чёрт ладана. (да и 21 веке писать что-то в командной строке когда есть кнопки в интерфейсе и  - это для полугиков, не умеющих пользоваться хоткеми ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Вы также можете искать по всем файлам на сервере, воспользовавшись FTP-клиентом WinSCP:
в верхнем меню
Команды ==> Общие пользовательские команды ==> искать текст.
И чтобы сервер искал только в файлах с расширением php, укажите
"Маска выбора файлов" ==> *.php

Answer (score 0):

Тот же тотал командер поиск по файлах темы. Вероятно **вам нужно править** ***файл ниже***:

**ваш_сайт\wp-content\themes\construction-landing-page\sections\promotional.php**

я думаю просто коментируйте вывод внутри условия наверное будет достаточно (судя по класу в ссилке), и наверное нужно **в скобках else, закоментировать if уловие**.

Пробуйте!